# How can I assign a variable in a select statement and also retrieve other data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, select

```
--external variables
@InputtedWardID int
as
begin
     --internal variables
     declare @wardID int 
     declare @WardName varchar(50), @NoNursesDpd int
```

Here I am trying to get the number of nurses deployed on a ward by using a function I have already created to count the number of nurses on a ward from an inputted ward id

```
select @NoNursesDpd = dbo.fnc1(@InputtedWardID), 
       @wardID, @WardName

select WardID, WardName
from WardTbl
where @InputtedWardID = WardID and @WardName = WardName

end
```

I am getting an error

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Does anyone know how to wrap this into one select statement?

Comment: Are `@wardID` and `@WardName` supposed to be arguments to fnc1()?

Comment: Do you need the result for further queries or just want it as part of the result set?

Comment: Why can't we write `set @NoNursesDpd= dbo.fnc1(@InputtedWardID); select @NoNursesDpd, 
@wardID, @WardName`

Comment: No fnc1 just gets the number of nurses deployed on a ward and this sproc is just supposed to retrieve that value from the function and two other colums WardId and WardName. No D Stanley I just want it as part of the result set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
select @NoNursesDpd = dbo.fnc1(@InputtedWardID), 
       @wardID, @WardName

select WardID, WardName
from WardTbl
where @InputtedWardID = WardID and @WardName = WardName

end
```

try this:

```
select WardID, WardName, dbo.fnc1(WardID)
from WardTbl
where WardID = @InputtedWardID

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the variable for further processing just include it in your result set:

```
select
    dbo.fnc1(@InputtedWardID) AS NoNursesDpd , 
    WardID, 
    WardName
from WardTbl
where @InputtedWardID = WardID and @WardName = WardName
```